# PHP md5() script for user login

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of 100 users and their passwords stored in a database.
I need to update the passwords using a salt as within the `UPDATE` query, `md5(name.salt)`.

What can be done and how?

for example :

```
user   Password    Salt
(1001   abc         "nnmm000ajdsl")
(1002   def         "nnjj000kdjsf")
```

I need to write a script to update the table by using md5 algo such that all password entries are changed to `md5(user.salt)`

what should i code?

Comment: Just for clarification, are the passwords plaintext and you want to replace them with an MD5 of themselves?

Comment: Don't. Implement password_hash and reset everyones password.

Comment: If the passwords are already stored hashed, then you can't simply update them... set a flag in your table forcing your users to reset their password next time they login, and update to a more secure hashing then (using password_hash() for preference).... and let every user know that they should login and reset their password as soon as possible

Comment: Don't forget to store the salt too, or should it be the same salt for every user (even less recommended than using MD5 at all).

Comment: yes, plaintext and replace them with an MD5 .

Comment: If they're plaintext; don't use MD5 to hash them, but use a decent hash that uses a different salt every time (e.g. password_hash())

Comment: One thing. md5 can be broke with luck in minutes, even sha1 can be broke in a while. You should instead use PHP http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php when available or http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php with CRYPT_BLOWFISH hashing and of course with salt. MD5 is really like no hashing at all and should not be used for password

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend having a look at the `password_needs_rehash` (http://php.net/password_needs_rehash) and `password_hash` (http://php.net/password_hash) functions.

---

If you still have plain text passwords, I recommend you write a script to hash all the passwords using `password_hash` and change your login code to check using it as well.

---

If you already have a weak hashing mechanism in place (like `MD5`), then you might want to either:

a) Rehash the password on login (using `password_needs_rehash` to check):

```
if (password_needs_rehash($hash, PASSWORD_BCRYPT)) {
    $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    // Store $hash in the database to replace the old hash
}
```

This means non-frequent visitors (or even old visitors who no longer return will have an old hash for a password.

or b) Write a script to hash your existing hashes again (this is generally accepted as an OK practice):

```
// Script that loops through each user
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $hash = password_hash($user['hash'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    // Store $hash in the database to replace the old hash
}
```

Then in your login script do this:

```
$password = old_hash_function($password);
// $stored_hash_in_database contains the value in the database for the username specified
if (password_verify($password, $stored_hash_in_database)) {
    // Log user in
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have to do this once so speed is not een issue. `SELECT` the password and id, then hash it with something safe (not md5, it's to old). Then `UPDATE` it into the database.

Something like this:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT id, pass FROM table");
$r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
$pass = md5('salt' . $r['pass']);
myqsl_query("UPDATE table SET pass = $pass WHERE id = {$r['id']}");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE users SET password = md5(CONCAT(password, 'yoursalt'));
```

But it's better to keep passwords hashed by native PHP function `password_hash`, like Naktibalda answered before.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use md5(), it is weak and insecure,
use a password_hash function instead https://www.php.net/password_hash

Comment: I think he want a MySQL answer, not PHP.

Comment: James: His question is wrong,
Kevin: Mysql hasn't any strong functions for password hashing, and if hashing is done in mysql, plain text passwords can be logged in general query log, so it is an additional security risk.